# iis basic auth doesn't work with my asp.net app

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

My need is simple, i have an asp.net mvc 5 web app and i want to show my app to my customer. For that i want to put my website on my iis and protect with basic auth the access.

The problem : With an empty folder it works well but when i deploy my app i got that :
**The page isn't redirecting properly**

With that link : http://XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FAccount%2FLogin%3FReturnUrl%3D%252FAccount%252FLogin%253FReturnUrl%253D%25....

Here my web.config :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

My config auth in IIS :
- anonymous auth disabled
- basic auth enabled

But it works well without my app so i think the

Thanks for help !

Comment: You're getting an infinite redirect loop. Just as an experiment, try removing the `<authentication>` element from `web.config` and see what happens.

Comment: i tried and it does nothing

Answer (score 0):

Ok i was sure the problem was'nt about the code but it was...

In the file Startup.cs I comment the default code :

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        //ConfigureAuth(app);
    }
}
```

And it works.